# ArcGIS Geocode Single Address Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-9.3, geocoding

How can I geocode a single address in python using arcgis 9.3?

I found http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Geocode_Addresses_%28Geocoding%29 - but this does a whole table, and I was forced to use a MDB file as the feature class and then inport and export from it.

Comment: Or if someone has example with VB, I could handle that too!

Answer (score 7):

The tool accepts a Table View parameter, which actually includes both true standalone tables as well as table views, which are like what layers are to feature classes. See [Working with layers and table views](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Working%20with%20layers%20and%20table%20views) in the help for more information.

You can create a table view that is a subset of the full table by using [Make Table View](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1873&pid=1865&topicname=Make_Table_View_%28Data_Management%29) and supplying a where clause, and then pass that table view into the Geocode Addresses tool.