# How to geocode a single address in Python Script/ ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, geocoding

How to geocode a single address (not table of addresses) in ModelBuilder and/or python Script? I want to enter the address and then geocode it. I am using arcgis 10.2.2

Comment: You need a geocoder, or a geocoder service, and you would use the 'Geocode an Address' tool in the model, where the input is a text variable and the locator is the geocoder mentioned above.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44732/is-it-possible-to-run-the-address-locator-in-arcgis-via-python and/or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16938/arcgis-geocode-single-address-python

Answer (score 3):

The [`geopy`](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) module is quick and easy for tasks such as this. Straight from the docs:

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
>>> location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
>>> print(location.address)
Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, ...
>>> print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
(40.7410861, -73.9896297241625)
>>> print(location.raw)
{u'place_id': u'9167009604', u'type': u'attraction', ...}
```

Note that it includes classes to use just about any geocoding service that is out there.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a quick little function to do this with the ESRI python libraries 
You can grab it at: https://community.esri.com/groups/arcgis-python-api/blog/2018/12/28/single-address-geocode-with-python or just check out the code below

```
import requests
geoCodeUrl = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates"


def singleAdressGeocode(address, geoCodeUrl, outSR = "4326"):
  #clean up the address for url encoding
  address = address.replace(" ", "+")
  address = address.replace(",", "%3B")

  #send address to geocode service
  lookup = requests.get(geoCodeUrl + "?SingleLine=" + address + "&outSR=" + outSR + "&maxLocations=1&f=pjson")
  data = lookup.json()

  if data["candidates"]:
    #woo hoo results
    coords = data["candidates"][0]["location"]
    return coords
  else:
    #no results
    return "Address not geocoded: " + address

print singleAdressGeocode("1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500", geoCodeUrl)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]/ Please [Edit] your answer to post the actual code, not just a link to it. Both questions and answers here are expected to be local to Stack Exchange, so that link failure does not destroy the content.